# Command not found error runing binaries after SSH transfer files

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, ubuntu-18.04

This is a naive question, I am aware of. But I have serious problems to run the commands to start the Flink cluster. I try to run a Flink cluster in a remote Ubuntu (18.04) server. I have already downloaded the flink binary folder and stored it in the server main directory.

Now via SSH from Windows machine and with a simple PuTTY application I connect to the server in my user space. Go into flink-1.9.0 directory and try

`./bin/start-cluster.sh`

First it says permission denied. Then I try the same with

`sudo  ./bin/start-cluster.sh`

and now it says:

> sudo: ./bin/start-cluster.sh: command not found

I also tried `/bin/start-cluster.sh` and   `./start-cluster.sh` inside bin and the same result.

I want to mention that I already did this process in my local machine and got no problems. Also, I suffer the same problem when I try to run binary Kafka in the same server.

I checked the Java version in the Ubuntu server and it looks OK.

> openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b11)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT

I found the solution. The problem is that sometimes when you transfer files from one machine to a server via SSH, there could be a change in the permission from the file.
It seems that the binary files from Flink and Kafka lose the executable permission. What I did was to change the permission into executable and then it works.

Use this command to check the permissions from the files inside the binary directory:

`ls -l filename`

If you get something like that:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 10490 floppy 17242 May  8  2013 filename`

then there is not an executable permission. You will need a 'x'. To change the permission into executable run the command:

`chmod +x filename.sh`

The result will be something like that:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 10490 floppy 17242 May  8  2013 filename`

This procedure can be improve, but if you need more information you can document about permission in Unix terminal.

Another possible solution in a different case will be to check if the relative path is working properly. Therefor, try to run the binary file using the full path of the user. If it works and the relative path doesn't work, then you have to check the environment.

Comment: Solution edited in the post above.